# Should i use gRPC in android (client) and node js (server) to make a video call?

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, grpc

I'm learning gRPC with android java is client and Node js is server side.
Now i want create a video call application. 
Should i use gRPC or other framework for this task ?
If not Could you give me another suggest ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;**

If i were you, i would go for gRPC.

I do not know if it will help you or not but i build video streaming applications with websockets. But with HTTP/2 i did look at gRPC and i like it a lot from a developer stand point. It is fast and i think it will become the standard over time. You can look at this sources if you like to read:

- https://www.infoq.com/articles/websocket-and-http2-coexist/
- https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/server-streaming-with-grpc-in-asp-dotnet-core
- https://medium.com/@EdgePress/is-grpc-the-future-of-client-server-communication-b112acf9f365